# SwiftUI Text Not Clearing When Navigating Back

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

My app works as expected, however, after I save the new shopping list with all of the entered fields, and I return back to the main screen, all of the fields on the Create New List Screen clear except for the "Shopping List" list. I am not quite sure how to fix this. Attached are images of my app, and the code.

[Home Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnilJ.png)
[Create New Listing Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uSIb.png)

```
import Foundation

struct ItemToAdd: Identifiable {
    
    var id = UUID()
    var itemName: String
    var itemPrice: String
    
}


import Foundation

struct NewList: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var storeName: String
    var budget: Float
    var item: String
    var itemPrice: String
}

import Foundation

class HomePageItem: Observable, ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [NewList] = []
    @Published var itemsToAdd: [ItemToAdd] = []
    
    var totalMoneySpent: Float {
        itemsToAdd.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.itemPrice.floatValue }
    }
}

extension String {
    var floatValue: Float {
        return (self as NSString).floatValue
    }
}

import SwiftUI

struct CreateNewListing: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var settings: HomePageItem
    @State var storeName: String
    @State var budget: Float
    @State var adjustedBudget: Float
    @State var itemName: String
    @State var itemPrice: String
    @State var newBudget: Float
//    @StateObject var viewModel = HomePageItem()
    @State var boolValue = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Store Name")) {
                    TextField("e.g, Trader Joe's", text: $storeName)
                }
                Section(header: Text("Budget")) {
                    TextField("Enter your budget", value: $budget, format: .number)
                }
                
                //List View of empty item and itemPrice text fields
                Section(header: Text("Enter Item and Price")) {
                    List {
                        HStack {
                            TextField("Item", text: $itemName)
                            TextField("Price", text: $itemPrice)
                        }
                        Button {
                            self.addToList()
                            print(settings.totalMoneySpent)
                        }label: {
                            Text("Add Item")
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                Section(header: Text("Shopping List")) {
                    List {
                        ForEach(settings.itemsToAdd) { item in
                            
                            HStack {
                                Text(item.itemName)
                                Text(item.itemPrice)
                            }
                            
                        }
                        
                        Text("Available Money Left: \(budget - self.settings.totalMoneySpent, specifier: "%.2f")").foregroundColor(budget - self.settings.totalMoneySpent  >= 0 ? Color.green: Color.red)
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Create New List")
            .toolbar {
                Button {
                    
                    settings.items.append(NewList(storeName: storeName, budget: budget, item: itemName, itemPrice: itemPrice))
                    
                    print(settings.items)
                }label: {
                    Text("Save")
                }
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(settings)
    }

    
    func addToList() {
        guard !itemName.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty else {
            return
        }
        guard !itemPrice.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty else {
            return
        }
        
        
        // Condition to check whether the data is already exit or not
        boolValue = false
        let newItem = ItemToAdd(itemName: itemName, itemPrice: itemPrice)
        for item in settings.itemsToAdd{
            if (item.itemName.contains(itemName) && (item.itemPrice.contains(itemPrice))){
                boolValue = true
            }
        }
        // check if boolValue is false so the data will store into the array.
        if boolValue == false{
            settings.itemsToAdd.append(newItem)
            itemName = ""
            itemPrice = ""
        }
    }
}

extension String {
    var floatValue1: Float {
        return (self as NSString).floatValue
    }
}


#Preview {
    CreateNewListing(storeName: "", budget: 0.00, adjustedBudget: 0.00, itemName: "", itemPrice: "", newBudget: 0.00)
        .environmentObject(HomePageItem())
}




import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var settings: HomePageItem
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(settings.items) { item in
                        HStack {
                            Text(item.storeName)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            Spacer()
                            HStack {
                                if(item.budget - settings.totalMoneySpent >= 0){
                                    Text("You saved \(item.budget - settings.totalMoneySpent, specifier: "%.2f")")
                                }
                                
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                NavigationLink {
                    CreateNewListing(storeName: "", budget: 0.00,adjustedBudget: 0.00, itemName: "", itemPrice: "", newBudget: 0.00)
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .foregroundColor(.orange)
                        .font(.title3)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("My Shopping Lists")
        }
        .environmentObject(settings)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView(settings: HomePageItem())
}
```

I have tried setting the item and itemPrice textfields to be empty strings.

Comment: Remove .environmentObject(settings) from CreateNewListing.

Comment: Also, as workingDog has suggested, you are not using `@StateObject` correctly in ContentView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach, clearing the `itemsToAdd` as the `CreateNewListing` View appears, and removing the second `NavigationStack`.

On MacOS 14.4, using Xcode 15.3, tested on real ios 17 devices (not Previews) and macCatalyst.

```
 struct CreateNewListing: View {
     // ...
     
     var body: some View {
   //      NavigationStack {   // <--- here, no need remove

           // ...
 
         .environmentObject(settings)
         .onAppear{
             settings.itemsToAdd.removeAll()  // <--- here
         }
     }
```

and

```
 struct ContentView: View {
     
     @StateObject var settings = HomePageItem() // <--- here
     // ...
```

I see you figured out how to calculate `Available Money Left`, well done.

EDIT-1:

You have a number of difficulties regarding the logic of your code,
where you have two lists, `[NewList]` and `[ItemToAdd]` that need synchronisation.

Here is my take, based on your code to `simplify` the flow of it.

The example code uses a `HomePageItem` data model with just one entry `items: [ItemList]`,
that represents a collection of `[ItemList]`. Each `ItemList` has an array
of `[Item]` together with the `storeName` etc...

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var itemName: String
    var itemPrice: Float
}

struct ItemList: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var storeName: String
    var budget: Float
    var items: [Item]
    
    func totalMoneySpent() -> Float {
        return budget - items.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.itemPrice}
    }
}

class HomePageItem: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [ItemList] = []
}

struct CreateNewListing: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var settings: HomePageItem
    
    @State private var item = Item(itemName: "", itemPrice: 0.0)
    @State private var newList = ItemList(storeName: "", budget: 0, items: [])

    @State private var isSaved = false
    
    var body: some View {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Store Name")) {
                    TextField("e.g, Trader Joe's", text: $newList.storeName)
                }
                Section(header: Text("Budget")) {
                    TextField("Enter your budget", value: $newList.budget, format: .number)
                }
                
                //List View of empty item and itemPrice text fields
                Section(header: Text("Enter Item and Price")) {
                    List {
                        HStack {
                            TextField("Item", text: $item.itemName)
                            TextField("Price", value: $item.itemPrice, format: .number)
                        }
                        Button {
                            addToList()
                        } label: {
                            Text("Add Item")
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                Section(header: Text("Shopping List")) {
                    List {
                        ForEach(newList.items) { item in
                            HStack {
                                Text(item.itemName)
                                Text("\(item.itemPrice)")
                            }
                        }
                        Text("Available Money Left: \(newList.totalMoneySpent(), specifier: "%.2f")").foregroundColor(newList.budget - newList.totalMoneySpent() >= 0 ? Color.green: Color.red)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Create New List")
            .toolbar {
                Button {
                    // --- more logic here
                    if !newList.storeName.isEmpty {
                        settings.items.append(newList)
                        isSaved = true
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Save")
                }
                .disabled(isSaved)
            }
    }

    func addToList() {
        if item.itemName.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty ||
            item.itemPrice <= 0.0 {
            return
        }
        // check whether the item already exist
        if !newList.items.contains(where: {
            $0.itemName == item.itemName && $0.itemPrice == item.itemPrice
        }) {
            newList.items.append(item)
            item = Item(itemName: "", itemPrice: 0.0)
        }
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var settings = HomePageItem()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(settings.items) { itemList in
                        HStack {
                            Text(itemList.storeName).multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            Spacer()
                            HStack {
                                if(itemList.budget - itemList.totalMoneySpent() >= 0){
                                    Text("You saved \(itemList.budget - itemList.totalMoneySpent(), specifier: "%.2f")")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                NavigationLink {
                    CreateNewListing()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .foregroundColor(.orange)
                        .font(.title3)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("My Shopping Lists")
        }
        .environmentObject(settings)
    }
}
```

Comment: that worked great! Thank you! I am having one more issue, when I go back to the main screen to view the store name and budget info, the budget resets back to the original budget amount so it will say "you saved 100". However when I create a new list, and go back it shows the actual saved amount. Any reasons for this? I tried debugging.

Comment: updated my answer with a different approach to cater for your new question/issue.