# Updating View Issue

Tags: swiftui

I am facing a strange issue with my app. When I create a new listing and I return back to the home page, the "You saved X.XX amount of money" is exactly what I expect. However, when I go to the create a new listing page and I go back again, the "You saved X.XX amount of money" is no longer the budget - the items that the user entered, it is just the original budget. When I create a new listing and go back, it updates it back to the correct value, but then repeats the issue when I go to the create new listing page and press back immediately. Any ideas?

Create New Listing Page:

[image: Create New Listing Page]

Correct Home Page View:

[image: Correct Home Page View]

Incorrect home page view after going to the create new listing page and tapping "back" without entering any data:

[image: Incorrect home page view after going to the create new listing page and tapping "back" without entering any data]

Here is my code:

```swift
import Foundation

class HomePageItem: Observable, ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [NewList] = []
    @Published var itemsToAdd: [ItemToAdd] = []
    
    var totalMoneySpent: Float {
        itemsToAdd.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.itemPrice.floatValue }
    }
}

extension String {
    var floatValue: Float {
        return (self as NSString).floatValue
    }
}


import Foundation

struct NewList: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var storeName: String
    var budget: Float
    var item: String
    var itemPrice: String
}


import Foundation

struct ItemToAdd: Identifiable {
    
    var id = UUID()
    var itemName: String
    var itemPrice: String
    
}


import SwiftUI

struct CreateNewListing: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var settings: HomePageItem
    @State var storeName: String
    @State var budget: Float
    @State var adjustedBudget: Float
    @State var itemName: String
    @State var itemPrice: String
    @State var newBudget: Float
//    @StateObject var viewModel = HomePageItem()
    @State var boolValue = false
    
    var body: some View {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Store Name")) {
                    TextField("e.g, Trader Joe's", text: $storeName)
                }
                Section(header: Text("Budget")) {
                    TextField("Enter your budget", value: $budget, format: .number)
                }
                
                //List View of empty item and itemPrice text fields
                Section(header: Text("Enter Item and Price")) {
                    List {
                        HStack {
                            TextField("Item", text: $itemName)
                            TextField("Price", text: $itemPrice)
                        }
                        Button {
                            self.addToList()
                            print(settings.totalMoneySpent)
                        }label: {
                            Text("Add Item")
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                Section(header: Text("Shopping List")) {
                    List {
                        ForEach(settings.itemsToAdd) { item in
                            
                            HStack {
                                Text(item.itemName)
                                Text(item.itemPrice)
                            }
                            
                        }
                        
                        Text("Available Money Left: \(budget - self.settings.totalMoneySpent, specifier: "%.2f")").foregroundColor(budget - self.settings.totalMoneySpent  >= 0 ? Color.green: Color.red)
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            .environmentObject(settings)
            .onAppear{
                settings.itemsToAdd.removeAll()  // <--- here
            }
            .navigationTitle("Create New List")
            .toolbar {
                Button {
                    
                    settings.items.append(NewList(storeName: storeName, budget: budget, item: itemName, itemPrice: itemPrice))
                    
                    print(settings.items)
                }label: {
                    Text("Save")
                }
            }
    }

    
    func addToList() {
        guard !itemName.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty else {
            return
        }
        guard !itemPrice.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty else {
            return
        }
        
        
        // Condition to check whether the data is already exit or not
        boolValue = false
        let newItem = ItemToAdd(itemName: itemName, itemPrice: itemPrice)
        for item in settings.itemsToAdd{
            if (item.itemName.contains(itemName) && (item.itemPrice.contains(itemPrice))){
                boolValue = true
            }
        }
        // check if boolValue is false so the data will store into the array.
        if boolValue == false{
            settings.itemsToAdd.append(newItem)
            itemName = ""
            itemPrice = ""
        }
    }
}

extension String {
    var floatValue1: Float {
        return (self as NSString).floatValue
    }
}


#Preview {
    CreateNewListing(storeName: "", budget: 0.00, adjustedBudget: 0.00, itemName: "", itemPrice: "", newBudget: 0.00)
        .environmentObject(HomePageItem())
}


import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var settings = HomePageItem()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(settings.items) { item in
                        HStack {
                            Text(item.storeName)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            Spacer()
                            HStack {
                                if(item.budget - settings.totalMoneySpent >= 0){
                                    Text("You saved \(item.budget - settings.totalMoneySpent, specifier: "%.2f")")
                                }
                            }
                            .onTapGesture {
                                print("")
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                NavigationLink {
                    CreateNewListing(storeName: "", budget: 0.00,adjustedBudget: 0.00, itemName: "", itemPrice: "", newBudget: 0.00)
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .foregroundColor(.orange)
                        .font(.title3)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("My Shopping Lists")
        }
        .environmentObject(settings)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView(settings: HomePageItem())
}
```

I have tried messing with the logic on the content view to update to the correct value.

Comment: You already had the same topic a few days ago, didn't you?  If so, how is it different from the last one?

Comment: State should always be private. State manages the identity of the View it should only be set internally.

Comment: you already asked this question before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78013695/swiftui-text-not-clearing-when-navigating-back/78014356  See my fully working answer